# Best way to change operators in string to their opposite

Tags: java, replace

I have a string like: `value += 5 * 3 - (2 / 4)` for example.

Now I must change all operators to their opposite, so:
+ to -
- to +
* to /
/ to *

My problem is when I use `replaceAll()` function

First time:
`string.replaceAll("+", "-");` I become: `value -= 5 * 3 - (2 / 4)`

Second time:
`string.replaceAll("-", "+");` I become: `value += 5 * 3 + (2 / 4)`
but it's need to be: `value -= 5 * 3 + (2 / 4)`

How can I achive that?

Comment: `replaceAll` does _not_ mean "replace all occurrences", but "replace all that match the given Regex". (This is probably not the primary problem, but it might also be a problem, as many of those chars have special meaning in regex)

Comment: Why not just loop through string char-by-char and replace single letter at a time to avoid such chaos?

Comment: I know how ``replaceAll`` works. That's why I know that it doesn't work with `replaceAll`. It's only an example why it doesn't work with `replaceAll`

Comment: @Arvind Yes thats a good Idea. Is there no other easy possibility to do this?

Comment: Morchul, no, @tobias_k is talking about a different problem from the one you're talking about. If you're not using regular expressions, you shouldn't be using `replaceAll` at all. Even without the parallel-replacement problem, `replaceAll` would be the wrong thing to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Map with the Characters to replace and iterate through the String like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<Character, Character> replacers = new HashMap<>();
  replacers.put('+', '-');
  replacers.put('-', '+');

  String value = "value += 5 * 3 - (2 / 4)";
  StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
  for (char c : value.toCharArray()) {
    out.append(replacers.getOrDefault(c, c));
  }
  System.out.println(out.toString());
}
```

This will print out:

```
value -= 5 * 3 + (2 / 4)
```

Comment: You can save a few lines by using `r = replacers.getOrDefault(c, c)`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just loop through string char-by-char and replace single letter at a time to avoid such chaos?

```
public String revert(String expression){
        char[] temp = expression.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; temp.length> i; i++){
            switch(temp[i]){
                case '/':
                    temp[i] = '*';
                break;
                case '*':
                    temp[i] = '/';
                break;
                case '-':
                    temp[i] = '+';
                break;
                case '+':
                    temp[i] = '-';
                break;
            }
        }
        return new String(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first replace your symbols (+,-,...) to some different ones that cannot be present in your expression e.g. +->A, -->B, ... and than all As to -, Bs to +, ... .
Other option is creating array of chars from your string and than iterate this array invert your symbols in situ. and than create String again.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple loop will work;

```
String exp="YOUR EXPRESSION HERE";
String newStr=""; 
//loop through the string
for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++)
{
    char ch=exp.charAt(i);//extract a charcter
    switch(ch)
    {
        case '+':
            newExp+='-';// replace + with -
            break;

        case '-':
            newStr+='+';// and - with +
            break;

        case '*';
            newStr+='/'// divide with *
            break;

        case '/'
            newStr+='*';// multiply with /
            break;

        default:
        newStr+=ch;// leave it as it is


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off just looping through the values, perhaps in a `char` array.

```
String val = "value += 5 * 3 - (2 / 4)";
char[] cArray = val.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
    if (cArray[i] == '+') {
        sb.append("-");
    } else if (cArray[i] == '-') {
        sb.append("+");
    // repeat for others
    } else {
        sb.append(cArray[i]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> value -= 5 * 3 + (2 / 4)